# Given that $f(n)= 7^{2n} + (2^{3n-3})(3^{n-1})$, show that $f(n+1)-24f(n)=25(7^{2n})$

Tags: functions, induction, divisibility

Given that $f(n)= 7^{2n} + (2^{3n-3})(3^{n-1})$, show that $$f(n+1)-24f(n)=25(7^{2n}).$$

Hence, use the method of induction of prove that $f(n)$ is divisible by $25$, where $n$ is any positive integer.

I don't quite understand how one would start, any advice would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*First part:*

**Given:** $f(n)= 7^{2n} + (2^{3n-3})(3^{n-1})$

**To prove:** $f(n+1)-24f(n)=25(7^{2n})$

**Proof:**

$$f(n+1)-24f(n)= 7^{2n+2} + (2^{3n})(3^{n})-24(7^{2n}) - 24 (2^{3n-3})(3^{n-1})$$
$$\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad= 49(7^{2n}) + (2^{3n})(3^{n})- 24(7^{2n})- 24 (2^{3n})(3^{n})$$
$$= \underline{25(7^{2n})}$$

*Second part:*

**To prove:** $f(n)= 7^{2n} + (2^{3n-3})(3^{n-1})$ is divisible by $25$ for $n\in\Bbb Z$

**Proof:**

① For $n = 1$:

$$f(1) = 7^2 + (2^0)(3^0)$$
$$= 49+1$$
$$= 50$$

$$\therefore \text{Statement is true for n = 1. As the above is in fact divisible by 25}$$

② For $n = k$:

$$ \text{Assume statement is true for } n = k$$
$$ \text{That is, } f(k) = 25p \text{ where } p\in\Bbb Z$$

③ For $n = k+1$:

$$ \text{We now assume statement is true for } n = k+1$$
$$ \text{That is, } f(k+1) = 25q \text{ where } q\in\Bbb Z$$

Now, using the result proved above:

$$f(k+1) - 24f(k) = 25(7^{2k})$$
$$= 24(25p)+25(7^{2k})$$
$$= 25(24p+7^{2k})$$
$$= 25q$$

So, if the statement is true for $n = k$, it must also be true for $n = k+1$

But statement is true for $n = 1$.

$$ \text{Hence, by induction, statement is true for all $n\in\Bbb Z^+$}$$

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Using the method of induction, when you wrote "We now assume statement is true for $n=k+1$", you should have written "We now prove statement is true for $n=k+1$ (assuming it is true for $n=k$)"

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Check that
$$f(n)=49^n+24^{n-1}$$

then

$$f(n+1)=49^{n+1}+24^n$$
and

$$f(n+1)-24f(n)=$$
$$49.49^n+24^n-24.49^n-24^n=$$
$$25.49^n=...$$